# pytorch nllloss function target shape mismatch

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, pytorch, lstm, loss-function

I'm training a LSTM model using pytorch with batch size of 256 and NLLLoss() as loss function.
The loss function is having problem with the data shape.

The softmax output from the forward passing has shape of `torch.Size([256, 4, 1181])` where 256 is batch size, 4 is sequence length, and 1181 is vocab size.

The target is in the shape of `torch.Size([256, 4])` where 256 is batch size and 4 is the output sequence length.

When I was testing earlier with batch size of 1, the model works fine but when I add batch size, it is breaking. I read that NLLLoss() can take class target as input instead of one hot encoded target.

Am I misunderstanding it? Or did I not format the shape of the target correctly?

```
class LSTM(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, embed_size=100, hidden_size=100, vocab_size=1181, embedding_matrix=...):
        super(LSTM, self).__init__()
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size
        self.word_embeddings = nn.Embedding(vocab_size, embed_size)
        self.word_embeddings.load_state_dict({'weight': torch.Tensor(embedding_matrix)})
        self.word_embeddings.weight.requires_grad = False
        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(embed_size, hidden_size)
        self.hidden2out = nn.Linear(hidden_size, vocab_size)


    def forward(self, tokens):
        batch_size, num_steps = tokens.shape
        embeds = self.word_embeddings(tokens)
        lstm_out, _ = self.lstm(embeds.view(batch_size, num_steps, -1))
        out_space = self.hidden2out(lstm_out.view(batch_size, num_steps, -1))
        out_scores = F.log_softmax(out_space, dim=1)
        return out_scores

model = LSTM(self.config.embed_size, self.config.hidden_size, self.config.vocab_size, self.embedding_matrix)
loss_function = nn.NLLLoss()
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=self.config.lr)
```

Error:

```
~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py in nll_loss(input, target, weight, size_average, ignore_index, reduce, reduction)
   1846         if target.size()[1:] != input.size()[2:]:
   1847             raise ValueError('Expected target size {}, got {}'.format(
-> 1848                 out_size, target.size()))
   1849         input = input.contiguous().view(n, c, 1, -1)
   1850         target = target.contiguous().view(n, 1, -1)

ValueError: Expected target size (256, 554), got torch.Size([256, 4])
```

Comment: Your way of use seems correct. Better add your exact error.

Comment: @akshayk07 added.

Comment: `model = LSTM(self.config.embed_size, self.config.hidden_size, self.config.vocab_size, self.embedding_matrix)` -> In this line, can you use the proper sizes directly? Might be causing the issue.

Comment: @akshayk07 model = LSTM(100, 100, 1181, shape of (1181, 100))

Comment: I guess you'll have to debug it yourself (like print statements with shapes of outputs and targets). This is because your understanding (regarding required shapes) and usage of the loss function is correct, afaik. Otherwise, you can remove the log_softmax in your model and change the loss to CrossEntropyLoss. Check if that works.

Comment: @akshayk07 That didn't work either. I think the model itself should be fine. It might be the problem that the loss function is not taking sequence inputs. I was able to work around by having a for-loop to calculate the loss for each index of the sequence, but I'm not sure if that's the way to do it.

Comment: @TYZ Check the docs for [`nn.NLLLoss`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.NLLLoss) describing shape again carefully. If input is (N,C,d) then target should be (N,d). In your case it looks like input is (N,d,C) so transposing dims 1 and 2 of input may fix your issue.

Comment: @TYZ Alternatively you could probably just reshape input to `(N*d, C)` and target to `(N*d)`.

Comment: @jodag Thank you for your hint! It is finally working! If you post it as answer, I can accept it.

Comment: @jodag For your second suggestion (concatenating `N*d`), will that affect how the input is processed by the network because each data point should be different from others.

Comment: @TYZ Sorry I'm referring to the input to the loss function, i.e. the network output. I was just commenting that if `x` is the (N,d,C) network output and `y` is the (N,d) targets then `loss_function(x.reshape(N*d,C), y.reshape(N*d))` is the same as `loss_function(x.transpose(1,2), y)`, at least for `NLLLoss`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your input shape to the loss function is `(N, d, C) = (256, 4, 1181)` and your target shape is `(N, d) = (256, 4)`, however, according to the docs on [NLLLoss](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html?highlight=nllloss#torch.nn.NLLLoss) the input should be `(N, C, d)` for a target of `(N, d)`.

Supposing `x` is your network output and `y` is the target then you can compute loss by transposing the incorrect dimensions of `x` as follows:

```
loss = loss_function(x.transpose(1, 2), y)
```

Alternatively, since NLLLoss is just averaging all the responses anyway, you can reshape `x` and `y` to be `(N*d, C)` and `(N*d)`. This gives the same result without creating temporary copies of your tensors.

```
loss = loss_function(x.reshape(N*d, C), y.reshape(N*d))
```